# Calling specific constructor when loading a view controller from segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface-builder, segue

I have added a segue between two view controllers using XCode 6 interface builder. However it calls the default constructor. How can I get it to call a specific constructor for the second view?

```
view 1 -> click button -> activates segue -> calls constructor of view 2 -> displays view 2
```

Comment: hey @mm24, did my answer help or do you need further explanation? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a segue this is unfortunately not possible, you can't further specify *how* the `destinationViewController` should be instantiated.

However, instead of using the Storyboard segue, you can instantiate the `UIViewController` yourself and just push it manually onto the navigation stack.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTap
{
   ViewController2 *vc2 = <your custom constructor>;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES]; 
}
```

(note that this mimics the exact same behaviour that the *push segue* gives you)

Otherwise, if you want to keep on using the Storyboard segue and your actual goal is to initialize certain properties of `ViewController2`, you can implemented `prepareForSegue:` and set the properties there.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
   ViewController2 *vc2 = segue.destinationViewController;
   // set properties here
   vc2.prop = xyz;
}
```

(note the code is not tested but it should convey the main ideas, let me know if you need further explanation)